# A simple code for conditional double summation?

Tags: summation, conditional

I wrote a code as follows

```
f[n_] := n^2 + 1;
x = 10; y = 2 x; d = 2;
A = Table[f[n], {n, y - x + 1, y}];
A1[d_] := Select[A, Mod[#, d] == 0 &]


Sum[f[n], {f[n], A1[d]}]
```

Now I want to write the *Mathematica* code for the following double summation:

$$\Large \sum_{{1\le l\le d}\atop{f(l)\equiv 0,\bmod d}}\sum_{{Y-X< n\le X}\atop{n\equiv l,\bmod d}} 1$$

Please give a simple and elementary code that is not complicated or advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the following would do:

```
Sum[
 Boole[(Mod[f[l], d] == 0) && (Mod[n - l, d] == 0)], 
 {l, 1, d}, {n, y - x + 1, x - 1}
 ]
```

This works because `Boole` converts `True` to `1` and `False` to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sum[If[Mod[f[l], d]==0 && Mod[n-l, d] == 0, 1, 0], {l, 1, d}, {n,y-x+1,y}]
```

Comment: Does replacing `Boole` with `If[#, 1,0]&` deserve a separate answer?

Comment: @Kuba, you are right. at the beginning when I compile his first code, it only gave $0$, but when I run it now it is OK!

Comment: @asad: It returned `0` because `y-x` equaled `x` in your example. So it was correct right from the start...